# Subtract background in image with Matlab

Tags: matlab, background

I have a list of images that i expect to have uneven illumination across the x axis only. The background estimation/model will be calculated in advance but only its shape will be given (so i will not have an empty background image that i can just subtract), I will just have the form/shape of it (for example linear).

Is there a way to subtract the background and get an even illumination of the image with just knowing its shape (and without having an actual background image)? I have attached an image from the Matlab library that was created using a linear background (background=-3*x+0.5). Can someone show me how to go from this example to the original image with just using the background shape?

[image]

I am also including the original image.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the shape, and the conditions you state are correct, then you have the full background information. It is, however, not possible to undo the clipping that happened (where the image has values 255, you don't know what the original value was).

This is how you would create a background image given the shape:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2Gi.jpg');
img = img(27:284,91:370); % OP posted a screen shot? What is this margin?

x = 0:size(img,2)-1;
background = 0.3*x+0.5;
background = repmat(background,size(img,1),1);

imshow(img-background)
```

The results looks not exactly like the original image, but most of that can be explained by the clipping.

I replaced your `-3*x+0.5` with `0.3*x+0.5` because the -3 makes no sense, and 0.3 makes it so that the background values remain in a meaningful range.

---

If, on the other hand, you are asking about *fitting* the linear model to the image data and estimating the exact background to subtract, then the problem is a bit more difficult, but not impossible. You can, for example, make an assumption about intensity uniformity across the x-axis if the illumination had been uniform across the image. You can then take the mean intensity along the x-axis and fit your model to it:

```
meanintensity = mean(img,1)';
plot(m)

X = [ones(length(meanintensity),1),(0:length(meanintensity)-1)']; % meanintensity = X*params    
params = X\meanintensity;
hold on, plot(X*params)

background = X*params;
background = repmat(background',size(img,1),1);
imshow(img-background)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for (both for creating a background image and the fitting). I appreciate the help!